# nonuniform box plot in r

Tags: r, boxplot

**Background:**

I have data that is bursty and non-uniform in time.
I am making boxplots of the data

**Problem:**

The boxplot in r is placing them uniformly distant.  I would like to place them at an x-time location indicating when they were collected.

**Questions:**

- Has this been asked before?  I tried google.  I tried looking through "boxplot in r" on CV.  I like answers and am uninterested in posting repeat questions for great minds to be annoyed.
- If it hasn't been asked, can I do the previous?  How?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: A solution using the `at` parameter to `bxp` is provided in the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/106083.

Comment: the examples under `?boxplot`, there is this `## Using 'at = ' and adding boxplots -- example idea by Roger Bivand :` etc

Comment: @whuber - That is truly beautiful.

Comment: @rawr - which R package?

Comment: `boxplot` is part of the base installation; its manual page notes it is in the `graphics` package.

Comment: nice plot @whuber. I would add an `axes = FALSE` to that `bxp` loop so that it doesn't draw and darken the axes for every iteration

Comment: @rawr - I'm using Rstudio.  When I look at the help I see no option for "at" as an input to boxplot.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @EngrStudent I think you're just not looking hard enough. [Here's the online documentation](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/functions/boxplot) to be sure. `at` is the last argument, right above the *Details* section. The last example also includes the line @rawr mentions, `## Using 'at = '`...

Comment: EngrStudent -- I'm using RStudio and I see it in the help just fine.

Comment: found it.  Also quite neat.  whuber is a Picasso - but I am just a student.  A single line solution here was much easier than elaborate code.

Answer (score 1):

@rawr and @whuber provided links in the contents.

A link is saying "go read a manual" not "here is how you do it".

So I went to this site:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html

And down at the bottom there was this text:

*"at" is a numeric vector giving the locations where the boxplots should be drawn, particularly when add = TRUE; defaults to 1:n where n is the number of boxes*

I ended up doing the following:

1. make a non-printing boxplot object using "myobj <- boxplot(...,plot=FALSE)"
2. make a vector of unique x-locations
3. call bxp with the "at" as a vector of the unique x-locations

Mycode:

```
h <- boxplot(y~x,data=mydata,notch=FALSE,
             boxwex=0.5,las=2,
             ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlim=c(xmin,xmax),
             subset = mydata$x>=thresh,
             at=ut,**plot=FALSE**)

myvector <- unique(mydata$x)

bxp(h,at=myvector,
    ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlim=c(xmin,xmax),
    xlab="x-value",ylab = "y-value",
    main = "My Boxplot",
    varwidth=TRUE)
```